# Can mods mark an answer as accepted?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Inspired by [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9164/22254).

The OP has said that it is the correct answer in a comment, but that they cannot mark the answer as accepted. Are the mods able to mark the answer as accepted so that other people will easily be able to find it?

Obviously there would need to be clear indication that something is accepted by the OP (so this is quite a niche scenario).

Comment: Yes, and Null will now mark his own answer below as accepted - no, just kidding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can't. Only the asker of a question can mark an answer as accepted.

There are a few questions on Meta Stack Exchange addressing this issue ([example 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period), [example 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-wrong-but-the-op-is-gone)) and the response is always strongly against adding this feature.

(NB I'm a moderator on another site.)

Answer (score 7):

**No.**

This has been asked before on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period) but rejected. [Accepting an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally

Only the question author knows which answer worked for him/her *personally* (if any) so only the author can determine acceptance.

In the absence of an accepted answer, votes determine which answer is listed first in the default "votes" view of answers -- so vote up answers like the one you found, like I just did!